# Error pushing to Heroku when route is removed from Play Framework

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.3

In my commit I:

- Removed the controller class: com.fractalemagic.Crashes
- Removed the relevant lines from conf/routes

Heroku build log:

```
-----> Play 2.x - Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8...done
-----> Running: sbt compile stage
       OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
       Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        44 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (13482kB/434ms)
       Getting Scala 2.10.4 (for sbt)...
       :: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
        confs: [default]
        5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24459kB/193ms)
       [info] Loading project definition from /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/project
       [info] Set current project to SomethingMagical (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
       [info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 25 Java sources to /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/classes...
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                      ^
       [error]   symbol:   class ReverseCrashes
       [error]   location: package com.fractalemagic
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:11: error: package com.fractalemagic.javascript does not exist
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.javascript.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.javascript.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                                 ^
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:16: error: package com.fractalemagic.ref does not exist
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.ref.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.ref.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                          ^
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                                                                     ^
       [error]   symbol:   class ReverseCrashes
       [error]   location: package com.fractalemagic
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:11: error: package com.fractalemagic.javascript does not exist
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.javascript.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.javascript.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                                                                                           ^
       [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.11/src_managed/main/com/fractalemagic/routes.java:16: error: package com.fractalemagic.ref does not exist
       [error] public static final com.fractalemagic.ref.ReverseCrashes Crashes = new com.fractalemagic.ref.ReverseCrashes();
       [error]                                                                                             ^
       [error] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
       [error] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
       [error] Note: /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/app/Global.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
       [error] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
       [error] 6 errors
       [error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
       [error] Total time: 22 s, completed Aug 2, 2014 8:46:52 PM
 !     Failed to build app with sbt

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play 2.x - Java app
```

I did get the same error while trying to run the project locally with Activator but after I ran `activator clean` it worked fine.

I noticed in the build logs that Heroku only compiles the code:

```
-----> Running: sbt compile stage
```

When according to: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support#activation

It should also clean.

After reversing the commit I was able to push to Heroku successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you've linked seem a bit outdated. You need to specifically tell heroku to do a clean compile, by setting the environment variable `SBT_CLEAN=true`

If you're using the heroku toolbelt:

```
heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true -a your-app-name
```

[Heroku Build Behavior](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support#build-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I solve the problem by **deleting all content under target** and then **re-compile**.